# RTL control byte

Tags: php, unicode

I'm aware there are a number of different topics discussing this, but I can't really find what I'm looking for. What I want is the ability to use the PHP chr() function to remove the RTL control byte from my inputs, but I can't seem to find a reference to this anywhere on any website.

I know I can target it from the Unicode character \u202E, but I'd much rather try and use chr() if possible... also, does anyone know what the URL encoded version of this is? (i.e. the null byte being %00 for instance) I've searched for a very long time to no avail now. I'd like to try and test out my scripts to make sure any holes or issues are closed, but again I can't find any.

I'm stripping out the various character control bytes too and also fixing some of the Windows latin 1 issues, I guess the only other question I have is, is there anything else I should reasonably be aware of?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm

#### Unicode Character 'RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE' (U+202E)

```
Encodings
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#8238;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x202e;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +202E
UTF-8 (hex) 0xE2 0x80 0xAE (e280ae)
UTF-8 (binary)  11100010:10000000:10101110
UTF-16 (hex)    0x202E (202e)
UTF-16 (decimal)    8,238
UTF-32 (hex)    0x0000202E (202e)
UTF-32 (decimal)    8,238
C/C++/Java source code  "\u202E"
Python source code  u"\u202E"
```

Also `chr()` would not be able to represent the RTL sign, as it's not in the ASCII, ISO-8859, or Windows 1252 encodings

> This can be used to create a one-character string in a single-byte encoding such as ASCII, ISO-8859, or Windows 1252, by passing the position of a desired character in the encoding's mapping table.

Comment: Thanks - I saw your reply as soon as you posted it but wanted to make sure I had a working implementation before I replied. I really appreciate the feedback on this one, it's a complex subject and I wasn't fully sure I grasped all the differences between the formats.

Comment: If this answer solves your issue, please mark it as such